# How to "unbind" Popups in Mapbox? Allowing only popups from markers within certain range(changing when user moves)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm trying to toggle between the ability to see tooltips or popups for markers on my map, depending on distance from them. There is an easy way to enable the popup, but is there any way similar to

```
marker.bindPopup(entries[i].text_content);
```

to remove the ability to view the popup again?

For reference, here is the complete part of code

```
$http.get(ApiEndpoint.entry).then(function(data) {
    entries = data.data;
    for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++){
            var lat = entries[i].lat;
            var long = entries[i].long;
    }
    var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({maxClusterRadius: 40, removeOutsideVisibleBounds: true, singleMarkerMode: true});

    for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        var a = entries[i];
        var title = a[2];
        marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a.lat, a.long), {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-symbol': 'post', 'marker-color': '0044FF'}),
        });
        if(haversineDistance(current_lat, current_long, entries[i].lat, entries[i].long)<26){
            marker.bindPopup(entries[i].text_content);
        };

        markers.addLayer(marker);   
    }
    map.addLayer(markers);
});
```

Where the haversineDistance function is used to calculate the distance from current location to the marker.

What I would like, is some piece of code which can be run in a loop, that removes all popups at a time interval, allowing me to use the if-statement again, to allow popups for markers within range, as the user moves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geolocating a client with Leaflet can be done with the `locate` method of your `L.Map` instance. Once started, you can listen for the `locationfound` event. The event contains a `L.LatLng` instance which contains the client coordinates. `L.Marker` instances have a `getLatLng` method which returns a `L.LatLng` instance with the marker coordinates. You can calculate the distance between them using the `distanceTo` method of `L.Latlng` instances. In code with comments to explain further:

```
// Markers in a LayerGroup
var group = new L.LayerGroup([
  new L.Marker([0,0]),
  new L.Marker([0,0])
]).addTo(map);

// Start geolocation (assuming map holds a L.Map instance)
map.locate();

// Listen for the event
map.on('locationfound', function(event){
  // If succeeded get client coordinates
  var clientLatLng = event.latLng;
  // Loop over markers
  group.eachLayer(function(marker){
    // Get marker coordinates
    var markerLatLng = marker.getLatLng();
    // Calculate distance
    var distance = clientLatLng.distanceTo(markerLatLng);

    // When within 40 meters
    if (distance < 40) {
      marker.bindPopup('POP');
      marker.openPopup();
    } else {
      marker.unbindPopup();
    }
  });  
});
```

References:

L.Map.locate(): http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#location-event

L.LatLng.distanceTo(): http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng-distanceto

PS. I am unable to test Geolocation at the moment so i freehanded this. Should be ok, hope ;)

Comment: It was the marker.unbindPopup i was looking for. :) 
I've found out that it's better to do the distance calculation on the back-end, and use a cache to store information on which ones to change the Popup on. In part your answer supplied the needed information, but also made me aware of the .distanceTo function which could probably replace the haversine function. So i'll mark it as right. :) Thanks.